# How to interact with closed source contract in golang?

Tags: ethereum

For example, I wanna to call `contribute` with closed source contract:
[image]

the original byte as following:

```
0x73e888fd0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

how to organize arguments with function signature in golang?

Comment: why flag as closed for this topic?

Comment: what do you mean by "close source contract"? is that like a contract you didn't write?

Comment: @NGDeveloper yes, the contract is not mine

Comment: ok, i'm not a Go user so i cant help you write code there, but you need a library like Nethereum in .net that can create an account object and a web3 object, then you can easly call any method from any contract just by using the contract address. if you want to use c# i can show you an example.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ABI encode the signature and params to form the input and ultimately create a signed transaction. Most, if not all, ethereum libraries can do this. For the sake of simplicity i'll use [`cast`](https://getfoundry.sh/).

1. Encode the siganture and params: `cast calldata "contribute(address)" 0xf50e662e1a50d44dfd1a1b6a07c2696805add040` where the `f50...` is the address parameter. This gives us -> `0x73e888fd000000000000000000000000f50e662e1a50d44dfd1a1b6a07c2696805add040`
2. We build a transactions as:  `{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'method': 'eth_call', 'params': [{'to': '$CONTRACT_ADDRESS', 'from': '$SIGNER_ADDRESS', 'value': '0x0', 'gas': '$GAS_LIMIT', 'gasPrice': '$GAS_PRICE', 'data': '0x73e888fd000000000000000000000000f50e662e1a50d44dfd1a1b6a07c2696805add040']}`. Note that this is not a complete spec for `eth_call`, refer to your client and library on how to correctly sign transactions based on your blockchain. For example if you want to use *cast*, you can read the docs [here](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/cast/cast-send.html).
3. Sign and send, obvously taking into account the correct nonce and gas needed.

This also assumes that the contract is un-permissioned, or doesn't have checks. Risk of interaction is on the signer.

Edit: I just saw that you want to do this in Golang. Here is how you would do it with one of the libraries. Your IDE should fix the missing packages.

```golang
import (
    "github.com/lmittmann/w3"
)

func main() {
    // assuming the fn returns a uint256
    sig := w3.MustNewFunc("contribute(address)", "uint256")
    input, err := sig.EncodeArgs(w3.A("0x…"))
    if err != nil {
        // 
    }

    txHash, err := signAndCall(context.Background(), input)
    if err != nil {
        //
    }

    fmt.PrintLn(txHash)
}

func signAndCall(ctx context.Context, input []byte) (common.Hash, error) {
    var txHash common.Hash

    // include your priv key somewhere and pass it to the signer below
    privKey := "..."
    tx := types.MustSignNewTx(privKey, signer, &types.DynamicFeeTx{
        // contract address
        To:        w3.A("0x..."),
        // correct nonce from network
        Nonce:     0,
        Data:      input,
        // depends on network
        Gas:       120000,
        GasFeeCap: w3.I("100 gwei"),
        GasTipCap: w3.I("1 gwei"),
    })

    err = c.provider.EthClient.CallCtx(
        ctx,
        eth.SendTransaction(tx).Returns(&txHash),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return [32]byte{}, err
    }

    return txHash, nil
}
```